# ReadByte on Socket takes indefinite time

Tags: c#, asp.net, sockets

I'm connecting to a socket and writing and reading data. My code below works fine on the windows forms application(Test App) and giving me desired output. However it is taking indefinite time on the ASP.net code behind.

```
for (int iCounter = 0; iCounter < messageLenth; iCounter++)
    byteArray[iCounter] = (byte)stream.ReadByte();
```

Everything on the IIS end is fine. I have other functionalities working fine and the website is working normally. Can anyone let me know what's happening with ASP.net

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a read-timeout on the socket? If you don't, then it is ***expected*** that `Read` and `ReadByte` block until either there is at least one byte available, or until the input socket is closed.

Comment: Timeout is set. Why it does work on forms application and not on ASP.net codebehind?

Comment: @Chandu that could posibly be a sync-context difference, then: the winforms sync-context will allow immediate calls - the aspnet sync-context had a habit of deadlocking if you try thay